# Sql limit rows returned by Inner Join

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Travelers.InsDate, 
                         dbo.Certificates.CertificateNumber, 
                         dbo.Certificates.Payment, 
                         dbo.Travelers.FirstName, 
                         dbo.Travelers.LastName, 
                         dbo.Travelers.DOB, 
                         dbo.Travelers.Address, 
                         dbo.Travelers.City, 
                         dbo.Travelers.State, 
                         dbo.Travelers.Zip, 
                         dbo.Travelers.Email, 
                         dbo.Travelers.BestPhone, 
                         dbo.Buyers.Name, 
                         dbo.Buyers.SalesRep, 
                         dbo.Sales.BoxNumber
FROM dbo.Sales 
INNER JOIN dbo.Buyers ON dbo.Sales.BuyerID = dbo.Buyers.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Travelers 
INNER JOIN dbo.Certificates ON dbo.Travelers.CertificateID = dbo.Certificates.ID ON dbo.Sales.BoxNumber = LEFT(dbo.Certificates.CertificateNumber, 4)
WHERE (dbo.Certificates.PaymentCode = '1')
ORDER BY dbo.Travelers.InsDate DESC
```

This query is returning multiple records with the same CertificateNumber. I want it to return a DISTINCT CertificateNumber but since the BoxNumber is a derivative of CertificaeNumber it is returning multiple rows.

I have tried Distinct and Group BY.

Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your join is mistyped. You should be getting an error when you run this as-is.

Comment: Nope, it runs fine but exposed another issue, multiple box sales, once I fixed this it runs fine!

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research another issue was exposed, BoxNumbers were sold to multiple buyers. Once I fixed this issue it ran fine.